# What is disabling my edit-and-continue in vb10 vs2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been using the vs2010 beta but I can't seem to get edit and continue to work.

- Compile -> Advanced Options -> Target platform is set to x86 (Compile -> Platform is disabled and set to Active (Any Cpu)?).
- Options -> Debugging -> Edit-and-continue is checked but grayed out. Presumably for the same reason I can't debug.
- Options -> Historical Debugging is set to Events Only. Disabling it doesn't help.
- I get no warnings when trying to modify files while debugging, they're just read-only (shows a lock icon in tab).

What are some other options that might be disabling edit-and-continue?

Comment: Yes, but that was never a problem in vs2008 as long as I set the target platform to x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same thing under VS2010 - think it's a bug in VS when targeting anything other than framework 4.0 [see here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=454348)